# .python_packages and .venv directories prevent func azure functionapp publish

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to deploy a Python Azure Function using Azure Function Core Tools. When I run the publish command, I receive the following error:

```
PS C:\[..]\func> func azure functionapp publish [function name] --build remote
Getting site publishing info...
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Deleting the old .python_packages directory
The file cannot be accessed by the system. : 'C:\[..]\func\.venv\lib64'
```

If I manually delete the `.python_packages` directory, I get:

```
PS C:\[..]\func> func azure functionapp publish [function name] --build remote
Getting site publishing info...
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
The file cannot be accessed by the system. : 'C:\[..]\func\.venv\lib64'
```

Then if I manually delete my `.venv` directory, the publish action is successful.

Is it possible to deploy *without* deleting these directories? If not, why is `func` unable to handle these actions as part of the publish process?

Answer (score 0):

- Deactivate & delete current virtual environment, create and activate new virtual environment:

```
deactivate
py -m venv env
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

- `python_packages` and `env` in `.gitignore` :

```
# Local python packages
.python_packages/

# Python Environments
.env
.venv
env/
venv/
ENV/
env.bak/
venv.bak/
```

- Make sure your function is working locally:

---

**- I have created a Python Azure function and deployed to function app using Azure Function core tools:**

- Created and activated new virtual environment:

[image]

**Local response:**

[image]

- Created a Python Function app with consumption plan in Azure Portal.
- Deployed the Function app with the command `func azure functionapp publish <functionapp_name> --build remote`:

[image]

[image]

[image]